# Go to first record function

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I would like to know the feasibility of writing a routine which allows for the user scrolling through a single form when arriving at the last record to be able to continue scrolling at the first record in the form. Basically i want to make one button that allows the user to be able to endlessly scroll through his records.   It it possible with code? Perhaps there is already a function in MSAccess allowing for this to happen? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears i worked it out. .Thanks anyway

```
If CurrentRecord = Recordset.RecordCount And CurrentRecord <> 1 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
Else
    On Error GoTo cmdRecordSuccessivo_Click_Err
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext
```

cmdRecordSuccessivo_Click_Exit: